# I cannot delete an item in a QList <QByteArray*>

Tags: c++, qt, memory-management, qlist, qbytearray

I am trying to delete (free memory) of all QByteArrays in QList of pointers to the QByteArrays. Here's my code:

in my .h file

```
        QList<QByteArray*> GroupWord;                                   //declare the QList
```

in my .cpp file

```
        quint8 k = GroupWord.length();                                  //get the last Index
        QByteArray& ref = *GroupWord.at(k - 1);                         //get the last Index
        qDebug() << "Length before deletion: " << GroupWord.length();   //print out the length before deletion
        qDebug() << "Before deletion: " << *GroupWord.at(k - 1);        //print out before del
        GroupWord.at(k - 1)->~QByteArray();                             //destroy the entry
        qDebug() << "Length after deletion: " << GroupWord.length();   //print out the length after deletion
        *GroupWord.at(k - 1)->append('l');                              //append to the 'assumed' deleted entry
        qDeleteAll(GroupWord);                                          //qDeleteAll the QList
        qDebug() << "After deletion 1: " << ref;                        //print out the ref to entry
        qDebug() << "After deletion 2: " << *GroupWord.at(k - 1);       //print out entry
        qDebug() << "After deletion 3: " << GroupWord.at(k - 1);        //print out the pointer
        GroupWord.clear();
        qDebug() << "After deletion 4: " << ref;                        //the memory is still there after ~QByteArray() and qDeleteAll() =(((((
```

Here's how I know the QByteArray in question has not been deleted:

The length of the QList still stays the same after ~QArrayByte();

[image]

I don't really know what's going on here :(

I know that I shouldn't declare variable like this, and just pass it around into voids; and when the QList gets out of scope, it will be automatically deleted. But, I just want to test something out :(

Thank you guys very much in advance,

And have a nice day, :X

Comment: You have multiple causes of undefined behaviour in your code: 1) calling `delete` on an object having already invoked its destructor explicitly and 2) accessing a `QList` element without first checking the validity of the index (`QList::at` doesn't perform bounds checking).

Comment: @G.M. I don't know; but I've edited my code to show that the length of the QList is still the same after `~QByteArray()` is executed. Did I do something wrong? :<

Comment: The `QByteArray` object doesn't *exist* after its destructor has been called -- its lifetime has ended.  Accessing the memory it used (via `GroupWord.length()`) is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @G.M. I am not sure if I get it correctly :< but GroupWord is a `QList` of `QByteArray*`; I just want to destroy/deallocate the memory used for the last index of GroupWord, this last index itself is a `QByteArray` pointer. And after calling `QByteArray::~QByteArray`, the pointer is still there, it's not set to null, or whatever it should be.

Comment: Don't use QList<QByteArray*> but QList<QByteArray> and you don't have to take care about deallocation. Using a QByteArray pointer doesn't give you any advantage but only problems.

Comment: @chehrlic So assume that I have a QList<QByteArray>, instead of a QList<QByteArray*>; should I deallocate everything just by calling `GroupWord.clear()`? Is that safe? Thank you very much in advance, :*

Comment: Yes it's fine since the objects are destroyed then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GroupWord.at(k - 1)->~QByteArray();` destroys the object but doesn't deallocate memory of its dynamic storage. You never removed the pointer from QList. Storing objects themselves instead of pointers would.. actually `QList` would store pointers and begins to manage the objects if they are `QObject` (`QList` is too clever for its own good , being designed to be idiot-proof). Which would lead to UB if you would try to call destructor.

`QList` "knows" its length only due to calls to its methods, it tracks it. The destruction you did is outside of its scope: `GroupWord.at(k - 1)` is a call of `QList` member, `->~QByteArray();` is a call of `QByteArray` method in context of objects returned by pointer from `at`.

You almost NEVER, EVER call destructor explicitly. Rare case when it's actually needed are some things like allocating objects with placement `new`, for them you cannot call delete as the storage doesn't belong to them.

`QList` uses a form of placement new inside of it, but that changes from version to version of Qt. What matters is that it's not a container with continuous storage for its elements. if you store pointers in `QList<QByteArray*>`, you have to remove them manually and `delete`  pointed object if that's appropriate: beware of double deletion or deletion of something that wasn't created by `new`. If you use `QList<QByteArray>`, `QList` manages that automatically, but it would always make a copy.

Comment: I think I somewhat get what you say. So assume that I changed my .h file from `QList<QByteArray*> GroupWord;` to `QList<QByteArray> GroupWord;` (without the asterisk); and I am very worried about memory leak; should I just apply `GroupWord.clear()`? Would it take care of everything?

Comment: @user49685 yes, it's a smart container and its exactly what's written in documentation. same happens with `std::vector`. The downside you get is that those lists are getting a copy. Your way isn't exactly wrong, but using `~QByteArray();` is very wrong, you actually cause memory leak because you cannot delete that object anymore.

Comment: I have one more question, what do you mean by 'but it would always make a copy' in the last paragraph? `If you use QList<QByteArray>, QList manages that automatically, but it would always make a copy.`? Thank you very much :*

Comment: @user49685 Not sure what it's unclear. Semantics of  `QList<QByteArray>` typename assumes that it stores `QByteArray`, right? Then in reality it allocates pointers into `QList`, but creates a new `QByteArray` object to store a copy, an instance of `QByteArray`. If you copy this `QList` or if assign whole new `QByteArray` to an element,  a copy assignment or construction would happen for `QByteArray` and its elements .  `QList<QByteArray*>` stores only pointers, they may point to non-unique `QByteArray`

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, and also, for your thorough explanation; I think I get it now. :* I am sorry if my question seems a tad naive, I just (kind of) understand what pointer is, and what reference is, like, just last night =)))) And the stuff above is my 'practice' on using pointers. Thank you so much, :* :*

Comment: @user49685 it's kind of problematic to try do that for C++ in general, by "try it" because C++ got  many nuanced rules you will not see and code will "work". And you include an ecosystem that doesn't work as "classic" C++. Qt essentially negates some C++ practices due to to most of internal working is hidden, it tries to emulate Java behaviour